# How can I set the DEBUG level in a Django application

Tags: django, logging

I am new to logging and am having difficulty setting the logging level to debug. I have created my own logger

```
# logger.py

from pathlib import Path
import logging

# Create a custom logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.propagate = False
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

# Create handlers
c_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
f_handler = logging.FileHandler('my_log_file.log')
c_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
f_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Create formatters and add them to handlers
c_format = logging.Formatter('myapp: %(message)s')
f_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
c_handler.setFormatter(c_format)
f_handler.setFormatter(f_format)

# Add handlers to the logger
logger.addHandler(c_handler)
logger.addHandler(f_handler)

def log(frame, obj):
    """Create log message and return the object."""
    path = Path(frame[0][1])
    module = path.stem
    line = frame[0][2]
    message_text = f'{obj} <{module}> {line}'
    logger.warning(message_text)
    return obj
```

I can create log messages in my application with

```
log(inspect.stack(), f'Something happened here {myobj.name}: {myobj.value}')
```

but it will not create messages unless I use the warning level

```
    logger.warning(message_text)
```

in the logger. If I change it to

```
    logger.debug(message_text)
```

nothing happens

I searched the application for *WARNING*, *DEBUG* and *level* but can find nothing that should affect my logger

I assume there is another logger that is over-ridding my level (Django perhaps)

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you share the `LOGGING` setting of your application?

Comment: I have no LOGGING setting that I can see :(

Comment: Thanks for the hint - I've added LOGGING to system.py and it now works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the hint given by [Willem Van Onsem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/willem-van-onsem) I added a [*LOGGING*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/logging/) section to Django's *system.py* and it now works as I expected

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'INFO',
    },
}
```